# Dynamic DIVs disappear on refresh? [JS only]

Tags: javascript, local-storage

*sorry if code is cumbersome I’m a very new “developer”*

So, I created a form and when you hit submit 3 things happen:
1. Input values are stored in an array inside localStorage.
2. Values are retrieved and are shown up in dynamically created divs.
3. Prevent submit (form is not sent).

https://codepen.io/jupiterisland/pen/Rjygmv

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>My Task Board</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <form onsubmit="return submitFunc()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Task:</label>
          <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Deadline:</label>
          <input type="datetime-local">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">important:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" name="button">Add Task</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="taskBoard"></div>

<script>
    var taskList = []; //build array

    function submitFunc() {
      var task = {
        //build objects
        desc: document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value,
        time: document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value,
        important: document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].checked
      };

      taskList[taskList.length] = task; //put objects inside array
      localStorage.taskList = JSON.stringify(taskList); //store array with stringify
      newTaskList = JSON.parse(localStorage.taskList); //retrieve array with parse

      for (i = 0; i < newTaskList.length; i++) {
        // display objects in divs

        var noteNode = document.createElement("div");
        var titleNode = document.createElement("h3");
        var pNode = document.createElement("p");
        var descNode = document.createTextNode(newTaskList[i].desc);
        var timeNode = document.createTextNode(newTaskList[i].time);
        titleNode.appendChild(descNode);
        pNode.appendChild(timeNode);
        noteNode.appendChild(titleNode);
        noteNode.appendChild(pNode);

        document.getElementById("taskBoard").appendChild(noteNode); //display divs

        if (taskBoard.childElementCount > newTaskList.length) {
          //remove excess divs
          for (n = 0; taskBoard.childElementCount - 2; n++) {
            taskBoard.removeChild(taskBoard.firstChild);
          }
        }
      }
      return false; //prevent submit
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is whenever I refresh the page after submitting new entries, the dynamically created divs disappear (while they’re still stored in localStorage).
How do I keep my submitted divs even after refresh?

I’ll appreciate any help/suggestion!
Thanks.

Comment: "_the dynamically created divs disappear (while they’re still stored in localStorage)_" The data (`taskList`) is in localstorage, not the divs. You will need to run your js loop onload of the page to check if there are items in localstorage, and if so, create the divs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So I need to create a separate function, add a proper if statement and then copy all the relevant createElement and appendChild lines into it?

Comment: Something like that yes. Basically, anything you create with JS will be destroyed once the page is reloaded so you have to have logic to check for this type of scenario on each page load.

Comment: I would suggest you not to insert to array like this method, use push() instead, and also use localStorage.set / get instead of directly use...

Answer (score 1):

If localStorage.taskList exists assign createDivs function :

```
if(localStorage.taskList){ taskList = JSON.parse(localStorage.taskList) || []; createDivs(taskList) }
```

Create Divs function is a part of your SubmitFunc() , where you create the divs :

```
function createDivs(newTaskList){
  for (i = 0; i < newTaskList.length; i++) {
    var noteNode = document.createElement("div");
    var titleNode = document.createElement("h3");
    var pNode = document.createElement("p");
    var descNode = document.createTextNode(newTaskList[i].desc);
    var timeNode = document.createTextNode(newTaskList[i].time);
    titleNode.appendChild(descNode);
    pNode.appendChild(timeNode);
    noteNode.appendChild(titleNode);
    noteNode.appendChild(pNode);

    document.getElementById("taskBoard").appendChild(noteNode); //display divs

    if (taskBoard.childElementCount > newTaskList.length) {
      //remove excess divs
      for (n = 0; taskBoard.childElementCount - 2; n++) {
        taskBoard.removeChild(taskBoard.firstChild);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! but now after I refresh the page and try to submit more values I get undefined for some reason :(

Comment: Fixed. And most importantly I understood how :)